# Show that $\sqrt[3]{2+\frac {10} 9\sqrt 3}+\sqrt[3]{2-\frac {10} 9\sqrt 3}=2$

Tags: radicals

> Find $\displaystyle\sqrt[3]{2+\frac {10} 9\sqrt 3}+\sqrt[3]{2-\frac {10} 9\sqrt 3}$.

I found that, by calculator, it is actually $\bf{2}$.

Methods to denest something like $\sqrt{a+b\sqrt c}$ seems to be useless here, what should I do?

Comment: Interesting. Looks like Cardan's formulas.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

We have

$\displaystyle 2 + \frac{10}{9} \sqrt{3} = 1 + \sqrt{3} + 1 + \frac{1}{9} \sqrt{3}$
$\displaystyle = 1 + \frac{3}{\sqrt{3}} + \frac{3}{\sqrt{3}^2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}^3}= \bigl(1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\bigr)^3$

Similarily, we have $2-\frac{10}{9} \sqrt{3} = \left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^3$. Hence

$\displaystyle \sqrt[3]{2+\frac {10} 9\sqrt 3}+\sqrt[3]{2-\frac {10} 9\sqrt 3} ~ = ~ \bigl(1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\bigr) +\bigl(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\bigr) = 2$.

PS: I have to admit that the first line is a little bit unmotivated. You need some experience in order to see these transformations (whereas verification is trivial). Alternatively, you can *hope* that both summands of this complicated sum actually lie in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})=\{p+q \sqrt{3} : p,q \in \mathbb{Q}\}$, make the Ansatz $2+\frac{10}{9} \sqrt{3} = (p+q \sqrt{3})^3=\dotsc$ and solve for $p,q$, which gives $p=1$ and $q=\frac{1}{3}$ as a possible solution. The answer by lab bhattacharjee explains how to calculate the sum more "mechanically".

Comment: How do you observe to get the result on first line?

Comment: @Martin, not sure what do you mean by "mechanically"? Also, solving for $p,q$ is non-trivial, right? I think my solution is more generic & universal than this one?

Answer (score 24):

$$S=\displaystyle\sqrt[3]{2+\frac {10} 9\sqrt 3}+\sqrt[3]{2-\frac {10} 9\sqrt 3}$$

So, $$S^3=2+\frac {10} 9\sqrt 3+2-\frac {10} 9\sqrt 3+3\cdot \sqrt[3]{2+\frac {10} 9\sqrt 3}\cdot\sqrt[3]{2-\frac {10} 9\sqrt 3}\cdot S$$

$$\implies S^3=4+2S$$ as $(2+\frac {10} 9\sqrt 3)(2-\frac {10} 9\sqrt 3)=4-\frac{100\cdot3}{81}=\frac8{27}=(\frac23)^3$

$$\iff S^3-2S-4=0$$

$$\implies S^3-2^3-2(S-2)=0\implies (S-2)(S^2+S+2)=0$$

Observe that $2$ is the sole positive real root of the last eqaution

Answer (score 13):

Let $x=\sqrt[3]{2+\frac {10}{9}\sqrt 3}, y=\sqrt[3]{2-\frac {10}{9}\sqrt 3}$. Then 
$$
x^3+y^3=4,\quad xy=\frac{2}{3}.
$$
The rest is yours.

Comment: Please explain how this can help the OP.

Comment: @DId: I think putting $y=2x/3$ one would get the same cubic equation as lab bhattacherjee  got.

Comment: @pritam You probably mean $y=2/(3x)$, not $y=2x/3$. Then $x^3+y^3=4$ becomes a quadratic (not cubic) equation in $x^3$ (not in $x$). Right, but what next? I recall that the object of interest here is $x+y$, neither $x$ nor $x^3$.

Comment: @Did: You are correct, I am really sorry.

Comment: But now it's easy: $(x+y)^3=x^3+y^3+3xy(x+y)$, so $(x+y)^3-2(x+y)-4=0$. Putting $S=x+y$, this is $(S-2)(S^2+2S+2)=0$, with one real solution $S=2$.

Comment: Nice hint, the "Cardano" trick backwards. Maybe could have added "expand $(x+y)^3$."

Answer (score 8):

Find $p$ and $q$ such that

\begin{cases}
-\frac{q}{2}=2\\[3ex]
\frac{p^3}{27}+\frac{q^2}{4}=\frac{100}{27}
\end{cases}

This of course gives $q=-4$ and

$$
\frac{p^3}{27}=\frac{100}{27}-4=-\frac{8}{27},
$$

so $p^3=-8$ and $p=-2$.

Now find the unique real root of the polynomial $x^3+px+q=x^3-2x-4$, which is of course $2$. Indeed the polynomial factor as

$$
x^3-2x-4=(x-2)(x^2+2x+2)
$$
and the second degree factor has no real roots.

This example clearly shows why Cardan's formulas have a very limited usefulness: they present the roots in a form that makes them unintelligible.

Here's Cardan's formula for third degree equations with only one real root: if $x^3+px+q=0$ and the discriminant

$$\frac{p^3}{27}+\frac{q^2}{4}>0$$

then the only real solution for the equation is

$$
\sqrt[3]{-\frac{q}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{p^3}{27}+\frac{q^2}{4}}}
+
\sqrt[3]{-\frac{q}{2}-\sqrt{\frac{p^3}{27}+\frac{q^2}{4}}}
$$

Comment: I would say that this example shows that one should not use Cardano's formula before testing for integer solutions.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg In a sense this is how Tartaglia and Ferrari made their problems obscure: they prepared an equation from a given (non easy to spot) root.

Answer (score 6):

Showing that $\displaystyle\sqrt[3]{2+\frac {10} 9\sqrt 3}+\sqrt[3]{2-\frac {10} 9\sqrt 3} = 2$ is the same as showing that $2\pm\frac {10} 9\sqrt 3$ has a cube root of the form $1 \pm a\sqrt 3$ (with rational $a$).

$(1\pm a\sqrt 3)^3 = (1+9a^2)\pm(3a+3a^3)\sqrt 3$, and you quickly check that with $a = 1/3$ you simultaneously get $1+9a^2 = 2$ and $3a(1+a^2) = \frac{10}9$, hence $2 \pm \frac{10}9\sqrt 3 = (1\pm\frac 13\sqrt 3)^3$, and your original expression simplifies to $1+\frac 13\sqrt 3+1-\frac 13\sqrt 3=2$