# Express this sum of radicals as an integer?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, radicals

I have read somewhere that the radical $\sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt{5}}+\sqrt[3]{2-\sqrt{5}}=1$ and I don't understand it. How do you solve this(when the RHS is unknown)?

Comment: This is what you are looking for http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/386488/show-that-sqrt32-frac-10-9-sqrt-3-sqrt32-frac-10-9-sqrt-3-2/386490#386490

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us consider the equation
$
y^3+py+q=0
$.
The theory of its solution tells, that we should consider 
$$
\Delta=\left(\frac{p}3\right)^3+\left(\frac{q}2\right)^2.
$$
If $\Delta>0$, then 
$$
y=\sqrt[3]{-\frac{q}2-\sqrt{\Delta}}+\sqrt[3]{-\frac{q}2+\sqrt{\Delta}}
$$
is unique real solution.

If you know this, the rest is simple. We guess $q=-4$, then $p=3$ and we have equation
$$
y^3+3y-4=0
$$
with an obvious real solution $y_0=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=\sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt{5}}+\sqrt[3]{2-\sqrt{5}}$. Write $a=2+\sqrt{5}$ and $b=2-\sqrt{5}$. Then
$$
x^3=
a+b + 3\sqrt[3]{a^2b} + 3\sqrt[3]{ab^2}
=
a+b + 3\sqrt[3]{ab}(\sqrt[3]{a}+\sqrt[3]{b})
=4-3x
$$

Now, the derivative of $x^3+3x-4$ is always positive, which means there is only one real root. By inspection, $x=1$ is that root.

Comment: Hmmm...what would happen if for some equation $\sqrt[3]{a+\sqrt{b}}+\sqrt[3]{a-\sqrt{b}}$ is going to be transformed into an equation with more than 1 root(both positive)? Would the root be 2 answers?

Comment: @MathNoob, if a cubic equation has more than one real root, then it has three real roots. In this case, the corresponding radical expressions would need to involve complex numbers, that is $b<0$ in example. This is the [casus irreducibilis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis).

Answer (score 1):

Let $~\sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt{5}}+\sqrt[3]{2-\sqrt{5}}=a.~$ Cubing both sides, using ${\underbrace{(x+y)}_a}^3=x^3+y^3+3xy~\underbrace{(x+y)}_a$, and simplifying, we have $a^3=4-3a$, whose only real solution, $a=1$, can be found quite easily via the [rational root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem). After dividing $a^3+3a-4$ by $a-1$, we're left with the quadratic $a^2+a+4$, whose roots are both complex, but $a\in$ **R**.