# Why $\sqrt[3]{{2 + \sqrt 5 }} + \sqrt[3]{{2 - \sqrt 5 }}$ is a rational number?

Tags: calculus, nested-radicals, rationality-testing

Why $\sqrt[3]{{2 + \sqrt 5 }} + \sqrt[3]{{2 - \sqrt 5 }}$ is a rational number?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1416720, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1008169, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1180599/, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/835955

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2404139

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$\sqrt[3]{{2 + \sqrt 5 }} + \sqrt[3]{{2 - \sqrt 5 }}=x$$
$$(a+b)^3=a^3+b^3+3ab(a+b)$$
Then $$2 + \sqrt 5+2 - \sqrt 5-3x=x^3$$ 
$$x^3+3x=4$$
$$x=1$$
$$\sqrt[3]{{2 + \sqrt 5 }} + \sqrt[3]{{2 - \sqrt 5 }}=1$$

Comment: When you cubed both sides where did the -3x come from?

Comment: $3ab(a+b)=3\sqrt[3]{{2 + \sqrt 5 }} \cdot \sqrt[3]{{2 - \sqrt 5 }} (\sqrt[3]{{2 + \sqrt 5 }} + \sqrt[3]{{2 - \sqrt 5 }})=3(\sqrt[3]{4-5})x=-3x$